# Need to display Views block in between two fields of a node

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have dynamic view block that i need to display between "body" and "last updated" fields of a Basic page node. (i.e. "last updated" field has to be at the bottom of a page).

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Where are you stuck exactly? You just stated what you want to get; writing what have you tried so far will show some initiative on your end :)

Comment: Thanks Aram for prompt response! I actually tried out the Field as Block module that you recommended. It does allow me to export the field into a block and control the order of display through the blocks admin page. But, first of all, it's not creating block for basic page content type, while creating fine for the article content type. Is there any alternatives to this module or different approach to the problem? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I would recommend the [eva module](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva). It's great for solving this problem