# How do I add a view between display fields of a node?

Tags: 8, views, blocks, comments

I have a view that displays a table at the bottom of every node. It's part of the content of the node so I want to have the "comments" section below the view.

However, the comments are a display field, which means they have to be in the same block as the node content. Since the view is a separate block I can't place the view between the node content and the comment section.

Is there a workaround for this?

Note that my content is created by the website community, so I can't use any solution that involves changing the contents of the nodes manually.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193833/need-to-display-views-block-in-between-two-fields-of-a-node

Comment: Is it always the same view and does every node of that particular type need to have the block displayed?

Comment: Did you try Layout Builder?

Comment: @leymannx yes for a given content type it is the same view block that I want to render above the comment section. It's always the same view. Note however that the content is created by the community, so I wouldn't want any proposed solution to affect the UX as far as creating content is concerned. I've added this to the post.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I wasn't aware of Layout builder, thanks for the tip. I'll do some reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with Drupal 8's Layout Builder.

Layout Builder is a module in Drupal 8 core that does much of what Panels did in Drupal 7 and before-- it allows you to create arbitrary layouts consisting of fields and blocks for content types and even individual pieces of content.

Since its part of core, this should be a safe long-term solution to rely on.

In this case, the rough steps would be:

1. Enable Layout Builder.
2. Go to Structure -> Content types -> MY CONTENT TYPE -> Manage Display.
3. Under **Layout options**, check *Use Layout Builder* and save.
4. Click the new **Manage layout** button that appears.
5. Your fields will be arranged as before.  Now, though, you can click **Add block** to add any block you want, including Views blocks.  You can then put the Views block between your page body and your comments.

This is just scratching the surface of what you can do but it should get you started.